# How to create a Stacked bar plot with percentage values and a line plot with percentage average in R using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]

How can we create a barplot similar to the one in the image using R and ggplot2? Any walkthrough will be greatly helpful.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please help others to help you: What have you tried? What are the coding problems you are experiencing? What is your expected output? Please make your question reproducible [MRE]: include a sample of your data into the question using `dput(your_dataframe)` [Helpful guidance for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really the place for walkthroughs or tutorials I'm afraid. It's for _specific_ programming questions. If you have a data set and have tried to create a stacked bar plot, then by all means post the data and show us where you got stuck. At the moment your question is off-topic.